# How to insert a second model into my ListView

Tags: django, django-models

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from library.models import Game
    from .models import Post
    from django.views.generic import (
        ListView
    )
    from django.template import context

    # Create your views here.
    def home(request):
        context = {
            'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('post__date_posted')[:5],
            'posts': Post.objects.all()
        }
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)

    class TitlePostListView(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'main/title_posts.html'
        context_object_name = 'posts'


        def get_queryset(self):
            title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
            return Post.objects.filter(game=title).order_by('-date_posted')[:5]
```

title_posts.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/title_posts.css' %}">
{% endblock styles %}

{% block content %}
        <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("{{ game.cover_display.url }}");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% 1000px;
            background-color: #171717;
    }
    </style>
        <div class="container margin-top-300">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-3 text-center">
                <img src="{{ game.cover.url }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>{{ game.description| safe }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 article-column-height text-center">
               <a href="#"><img class="article-image-height" src="{{ post.article_image.url }}"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 article-column-height">
              <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.article_title }}</a></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Article Title Place Holder")
    content = HTMLField(default="Article Content Pace Holder")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    game = models.ForeignKey('library.Game', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png')

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    cover = models.ImageField()
    cover_display = models.ImageField(default='default.png')
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Edit: I have a page that displays posts/articles for a certain video game. Currently my query returns the posts from the Post model for that video game. However, I am unsure of how to also display the video games description and images on that same page. The {{game.cover.url}}, ((game.description}}, and {{game.cover_display.url}} do not show up when I load the page because I am unsure how to also get that specific games objects from the Game model.

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% with post.game.set.all|first as game %}
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("{{ game.cover_display.url }}");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 1000px;
        background-color: #171717;
}
</style>
    <div class="container margin-top-300 black">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
            <img src="{{ game.cover.url }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>{{ game.description| safe }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endwith %}
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 article-column-height text-center">
           <a href="#"><img class="article-image-height" src="{{ post.article_image.url }}"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 article-column-height">
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.article_title }}</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Question is not clear yet. What are you trying to do? Insert that model into ListView means?

Comment: I have a page that displays posts/articles for a certain video game. Currently my query returns the posts from the Post model for that video game. However, I am unsure of how to also display the video games description and images on that same page. The {{game.cover.url}}, ((game.description}}, and {{game.cover_display.url}} do not show up when I load the page because I am unsure how to also get that specific games objects from the Game model.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ForeignKey. So use like this in loop

```
{% with post.game_set.all|first as game %}
  <img src="{{ game.url }}" />
{% endwith %}
```

As you are already filtering by game then only add the game in your get_context_data() method

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(TitlePostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
    return context
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not return anything :(

Comment: Can you post your posts for loop?

Comment: I added it. Is this what you meant?

Comment: it should be post.game_set.all. You used post.game.set.all

Comment: I fixed it but it still didn't return anything. If it did work wouldn't it display it above every post because its in my for loop? I'm only wanting it display once. I was thinking maybe I could add something like get_context_data to my view but I'm still unsure how to get the data for that specific game.

Comment: Actually as you are filtering already by game title so game always should be same then add it to your get_context_data() method and show in template.